# How can I add directions using Google Map URLs from an array?

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm using a WordPress directory theme: there is an address with street, number and city.

I get values from an array convert them into a google map location link, (a button that says "Open in Google map"). I want to change this to open at google map and route the plan from my location.

I think that `$url` has the address and is added to the google map url, but should I add more so that it will also route the plan from my location?

```
if( !function_exists('estate_listing_address') ):
function estate_listing_address($post_id,$col=3){

$property_address   =   esc_html( get_post_meta($post_id, 'property_address', true) );
$property_city      =   strip_tags (  get_the_term_list($post_id, 'property_city', '', ', ', '') );
$url                =   urlencode($property_address.','.$property_city);
$google_map_url     =   "http://maps.google.com/?q=".$url;

$return_string.= ' <a href="'.$google_map_url.'" target="_blank" class="button">'.__('Route plan','wpestate').'</a>';

return  $return_string;
}
endif;
```

Comment: thanks, for correcting the question, does this means that this is not possible ? Because no body wrote nothing !

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is kind of off since you can already use the values from the array. I can understand your concern like this, you want to change the request from **showing the location** to **getting the route/directions**.

So here's what you need to do if that's the case:

To get a route between 2 points, you need an `origin` and a `destination`. You can just store them in a variable like this:

```
$origin = "Chicago";
$destination = "Indianapolis";
```

I used Chicago here as a sample origin and Indianapolis as sample destination. But in for your case, you must change the origin to your location and the destination to the value from the array.

Now we urlencode the origin and destination to convert them to a valid url format in case there are special characters and store them in $url variable just like you did:

```
$url = urlencode('&origin='.$origin.'&destination='.$destination);
```

But this time, the `origin` and `destination` are set by using them as parameters.

And lastly for the google maps url, you can just put `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1` in your url string like this then add the $url at the end:

```
$google_map_url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1".$url;
```

So without the variables, the request is basically like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Chicago&destination=Indianapolis

You may read more in the official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

> Please be advised that abusing this functionality can be a violation to **Google Maps Terms of Service**. It is in the ***Prohobited Conduct*** section of TOS that When using Google Maps/Google Earth, you may not (or allow those acting on your behalf to):
>
> *a. redistribute or sell any part of Google Maps/Google Earth or create a new product or service based on Google Maps/Google Earth (unless you use the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs in accordance with their terms of service);*
>
> *b. copy the Content (unless you are otherwise permitted to do so by the Using Google Maps, Google Earth, and Street View permissions page or applicable intellectual property law, including "fair use");*
>
> and
>
> *d. use Google Maps/Google Earth to create or augment any other mapping-related dataset (including a mapping or navigation dataset, business listings database, mailing list, or telemarketing list) for use in a service that is a substitute for, or a substantially similar service to, Google Maps/Google Earth*
>
> Read more about Google Maps TOS
> [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en_ph/help/terms_maps.html).
>
> **I would suggest using the [Google Maps Javascript Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) for applications like this instead of using the maps.google.com URL request. (In fact, it is much cooler to show the map in your page instead of navigating to a new page or popping up a new tab just to get directions)**

Hope this helps!!

Comment: well yes, really helped a lot ! Thank you,

Comment: no problem. can you atleast upvote/accept my answer if it solved your problem? :D

Comment: There is even better and documented way to construct URL using Google Maps URLs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Comment: Updated with the official steps of using Maps URLs. :)